# About std::move behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, move-semantics

I played a little with `std::move` and I noticed something strange:

```
string && foo(string && x) {
    string && a = move(x);
    return move(a); //both x and a = "asdfgh"
}

int main(){

    string x,aa;

    aa = "asdfgh";
    x = foo(move(aa)); 
    //aa = "", x = "asdfgh" 

    aa = "asdf";
    x = move(aa); 
    //aa = "", x ="asdf"
}
```

The behavior in `main` is clear but why in `foo` after the `move` was called, `x` is not empty? Why it didn't "steal" from `x`?

Comment: Too bad you have two things called `x`. It makes it hard to understand your question.

Comment: Neither `std::move` nor binding to `X&&` move anything at all.

Comment: @fredoverflow you mean in the line  `string && a = move(x);`?

Comment: In general. A move is performed by the move constructor `X(X&&)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this code :-

```
int main()
{

    string aa;
    aa = "asdf";
    string &&x = move(aa); 
    x[0]='b';
    cout<<boolalpha<<aa<<'\t'<<aa.empty()<<'\n';
    string y = move(aa);
    y[0]='c';
    cout<<aa<<'\t'<<aa.empty()<<'\n';
    return true;
}
```

Output :-

```
bsdf        false
            true
```

Clearly `x` is an `rvalue reference` to `aa` & not a different object (which is why on changing `x` there was a change in `aa`). Hence `aa` wasn't emptied. However on the other hand `y` is a different object from `aa` & hence the `std::move` statement emptied `aa`.

Hence, a similar behaviour is shown by your code in the `foo` function. As `x` & `a` in `foo` are `rvalue references` to `aa`, your code doesn't empty `aa`.

Answer (score 4):

Because, in `foo`, `a` is a r-value *reference*. `a` and local variable `x` are the same object.

Comment: So what happens in `string && a = move(x);`? is only the move assignment operator being called here?

Comment: @kuhaku , there is no assigment operator call. _It just binds a reference_. Your whole `foo` function is a no-op: it takes an r-value reference and returns it unchanged. It is completely optimised away by compiler.